# Possible deserialization issue with spring-kafka 3.1.3

Tags: spring-kafka

I just upgraded some of my applications from `spring-boot 3.2.3` to `spring-boot 3.2.4` which updated `spring-kafka` from `3.1.2` to `3.1.3` and found some of my tests failing.

The issue only occurs when processing events that lead to an deserialization exception. In this case my custom `FailedDeserializationFunction` is called, however the faulty event seems to be propagated to one of the configured retry-topics and causes an infinite loop.

Downgrading to `spring-boot 3.2.3` / `spring-kafka 3.1.2` fixes the issue.

Sample project: [here](https://github.com/tzie0062/deser-issue-spring-kafka-3-1-3)

Running the tests with `spring-kafka 3.1.3` yields:

```
 INFO 143594 --- [kafka-dlt] [yListener-0-C-1] c.e.k.FailedDeserializationFunction      : Failed to deserialize event - returning default
 ERROR 143594 --- [kafka-dlt] [yListener-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer    : Dead-letter publication to test-topic-kafka-dlt-retry-0 failed for: test-topic-0@1
    
    org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class [B to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer specified in value.serializer
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:1003) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:947) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:1050) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
```

Question: am I doing something wrong or is this a regression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the report an great example!

The problem is here:

```
@Header(name = SerializationUtils.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_EXCEPTION_HEADER, required = false) byte[] deSerializationErrorHeader
```

Must be a `RecordHeader` now instead of `byte[]`.

The fix has been done here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/3114

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Using a `RecordHeader` fixes the problem!